# How do I go to a specific page in React based on a URL param

Tags: reactjs, react-router

As an example when entering `http://localhost:3000/ui/?goto=/ui/entity/e2` in the browser I'd like to go to the Entity component e2.

This is my router:

```
<Route path="/ui/" component={App}>
        <IndexRoute component={EntitiesPage} />
        <Route      component={Entity}       path="entity/:id" />
        <Route      component={NotFound}     path="*" />
</Route>
```

This is the App component:

```
import React from 'react'

const App = React.createClass( {
    render() {
        let gotoUrl = this.props.location.query.goto;
        if (gotoUrl) {
            // go here: gotoUrl;
        } else {
            return (
                <div className="App">
                    {this.props.children}
                </div>
            )
        }
    }
})
export default App
```

this.context is empty.
this.props has:

- history
- location
- route
- routeParams (empty)
- routes

UPDATE:
I've ended up using this:

```
import React from 'react'
import { withRouter } from 'react-router'

const App = React.createClass( {
    componentWillMount() {
        let gotoUrl = this.props.location.query.goto;
        if (gotoUrl) {
            this.props.router.replace(gotoUrl);
        }
    },

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="App">
                {this.props.children}
            </div>
        );
    }
})
export default withRouter(App)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing that might be tripping you up is that **`render` should have no side effects**.

A "side effect" is anything that changes what's going on in your app*: updating state, making AJAX calls, or in this case, altering the page location. The `render` method should only *read from the current state of the component, then return a value*.

Because you're already using `React.createClass`, the best way to handle this is by adding a separate method that React handles specially: `componentWillMount`. I'd recommend you put your "redirect" logic here.

In order to properly change the page location, you'll need access to the browser history object which `react-router` manipulates. You can import this from the `react-router` library itself and directly call methods on it:

```
// At top of file
import { browserHistory } from 'react-router'

// Then, in your component:
componentWillMount() {
  let gotoUrl = this.props.location.query.goto;
    if (gotoUrl) {
        // NOTE: this may have security implications; see below
        browserHistory.push(gotoUrl);
    }
}
```

Source: [documentation](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/NavigatingOutsideOfComponents.md).

I'd suggest that, instead of using `query.goto`, you instead select a parameter that can be easily validated, such as the entity ID itself (a simple regex can make sure it's valid). Otherwise, an unscrupulous user might send a link to another user and cause them to access a page that they didn't mean to.

*Note: there are stricter definitions of "side effect" out there, but this one is pretty useful for React development.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `browserHistory`

```
import { browserHistory } from 'react-router';
...
if (gotoUrl) {
  browserHistory.push(gotoUrl)
}
```

Let me know if this works